# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I'm using `viewForFooterInSection` because when I use

```
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

my button is not touchable. That's why I want to manually show where the last section is.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 && section == 1)
   {
if(myFooterView == nil) {
    //allocate the view if it doesn't exist yet
    myFooterView  = [[UIView alloc] init];


    //create the button
    UIButton *footButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [footButton setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 100, 30)];

    //set title, font size and font color
    [footButton setTitle:@"Go Home" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [footButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];

    //set action of the button
    [footButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickPressed:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //add the button to the view
    [myFooterView addSubview:footButton];
}

//return the view for the footer
return myFooterView;
   }
}
```

This line of code is giving me the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, and I'm sure the section exists:

```
if(control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 && section == 1)
```

Can't see what the problem is.

**EDIT:**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *control;


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self setTitle:_actor.actorNaam];
NSLog(@"Actor viewwillappear %@", _actor.actorNaam);

NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Actor", @"Object", @"Operation", @"Goal", nil];
control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items]; //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
control.selectedSegmentIndex = segmentPushed;
control.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
control.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
control.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
```

Comment: Is there a (symbolic) stacktrace you can post?

Comment: Where is `control` initialized?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using ARC environment,

you have declared "control" as retain but it is not being retained in ARC environment due to improper way of assignment.

make a change:

```
control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
```

use

```
self.control = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items];
```

using **self** will invoke the default setter and your object will be retained which is not being done at the moment.

Comment: Actually, the first example is the only one that is appropriate - the second one is leaking memory.

Comment: thanks @H2CO3, I corrected the answer.I suggested the solution with ARC in my mind but end up referring to non-ARC in the end.